# Change the buttons class when toggling between divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have just started to learn javascript today and I'm trying to make a menu that will toggle between divs.

My problem is I can't work out how to change the buttons class when toggling between divs.

For example, if button two is clicked the class will change from btn-purple to btn-blue, and button one class will change from btn-blue to btn-purple and will also toggle between divs.

```js
window.toggle = (id, btn) => {
  const button = document.getElementById(btn);

  document.querySelectorAll('.menus').forEach(menu => {
    if (menu.style.display === 'block') {
      menu.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });

  changeClass(button, 'btn-purple', 'btn-blue');
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
};

window.changeClass = (e, r, a) => {
  e.classList.remove(r);
  e.classList.add(a);
};
```

```css
.btn-blue {
  background-color: #1d8dee;
}

.btn-blue:hover {
  background-color: #4fa7ee;
}

.btn-purple {
  background-color: #8064A2;
}

.btn-purple:hover {
  background-color: #7237e4;
}

.menus {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center; overflow: auto; white-space: nowrap;">
  <button class="btn btn-blue" id="btn1" onclick="toggle('menu1', 'btn1');">Button One</button> &nbsp;
  <button class="btn btn-purple" id="btn2" onclick="toggle('menu2', 'btn2');">Button Two</button>
</div>

<div id="menu1" class="menus" style="display: block;"><br>
  <p>Menu One</p>
</div>

<div id="menu2" class="menus"><br>
  <p>Menu Two</p>
</div>
```

I was hoping maybe someone could help me work out why or point me in the right direction or if there is an easier/better way to do what I achieve.

Edit: I forgot to mention I have more than two divs and buttons I just showed two of each for an example

Comment: can you clarify what is supposed to happen please? If you click one button it's class will change but the other buttons - should their class revert to the default or do they not change?

Comment: If button two is clicked the class on button two will change to btn-bule and button one class will be changed to btn-purple.

And then if button one is clicked again the class for one button one will change to btn-bule and button two will be btn-purple.

Comment: @apklitestore so exactly what I did in my answer?

Comment: Please if there's no specific reason, stop bloating the `window` scope.

Comment: @bluejambo It's almost what i'm trying achieve but i'm trying to make the buttons switch classes. Sorry if i didn't explain my problem correctly.

Comment: Don't use inline `on*` attributes handlers. Just like you should not use inline `style` attributes. CSS and JS should be in one place only, and that's their respective style or script tags.

Comment: @apklitestore yeah, I just got what you wanted to achieve, answer is gone

Comment: You are changing button class from `btn-purple` to `btn-blue` but you also need to change rest of the buttons to `btn-purple`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers.

Try using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation): create one handler to handle the button clicks. The menu to show can be identified using a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Something like:

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

addSomeButtonsAndMenus4Demo()

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains(`btn`)) {
    const clickedBtn = evt.target;
    // reset all menus
    document.querySelectorAll(`.menus`)
      .forEach(m => m.classList.add(`hidden`));
    // set visibility for menu from clicked button
    document.querySelector(`#${clickedBtn.dataset.menu}`)
      .classList.remove(`hidden`);
    // reset all .btn
    document.querySelectorAll(`.btn-blue`)
      .forEach(b => b.classList.replace(`btn-blue`, `btn-purple`));
    // set clicked to selected class
    clickedBtn.classList.replace(`btn-purple`, `btn-blue`);
  }
}

// --- demo stuff ---
function addSomeButtonsAndMenus4Demo() {
  const num2Txt = numbers2Text();
  // add a few buttons/menus to demonstrate that
  // the delegated handler handles all buttons    
  for (let i = 3; i < 7; i += 1) {
    const bttnNumber = num2Txt(i);
    const btnHtml = document.querySelector(`#btn1`).outerHTML
      .replace(`btn1`, `btn${i}`).replace(`menu1`, `menu${i}`)
      .replace(`One`, `${bttnNumber}`).replace(`btn-blue`, `btn-purple`);
    document.querySelector(`.btnBlock`)
      .insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, btnHtml);
    const menuHtml = document.querySelector(`#menu2`).outerHTML
      .replace(`menu2`, `menu${i}`).replace(`Two`, `${bttnNumber}`);
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, menuHtml);
  }
}

function numbers2Text() {
  const nums = {
    Three: 3,
    Four: 4,
    Five: 5,
    Six: 6,
  }
  return value =>
    Object.entries(nums).find(([key, val]) => val === value).shift();
}
```

```css
.btnBlock {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn {
  margin-right: 0.8rem;
}

.btn-blue {
  background-color: #1d8dee;
}

.btn-blue:hover {
  background-color: #4fa7ee;
}

.btn-purple {
  background-color: #8064A2;
}

.btn-purple:hover {
  background-color: #7237e4;
}

.menus {
  text-align: center;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="btnBlock">
  <button class="btn btn-blue" id="btn1" data-menu="menu1">Button One</button>
  <!--                                   ^ data-attribute to identify the menu -->
  <button class="btn btn-purple" id="btn2" data-menu="menu2">Button Two</button>
</div>

<div id="menu1" class="menus">
  <p>Menu One</p>
</div>

<div id="menu2" class="menus hidden">
  <!--                         ^ use css class to hide -->
  <p>Menu Two</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `m => m.classList.add('hidden')` work with what the API offers: `m => m.hidden = true`

Comment: @connexo Won't edit the accepted answer, but [here's a fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-dnecdq?file=index.js) using your suggestion. Not sure if this is [the right use case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden) for the `hidden` property though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nextElementSibling` or `previousElementSibling` (which will select `btn2` if `btn1` is clicked or vice versa) with your `changeClass` function to change class of other button from  `btn-blue` to `btn-purple`.

```js
const toggle = (id, btn) => {
  const button = document.getElementById(btn);

  document.querySelectorAll('.menus').forEach(menu => {
    if (menu.style.display === 'block') {
      menu.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });

  changeClass(button, 'btn-purple', 'btn-blue');
  changeClass(button.nextElementSibling||button.previousElementSibling, 'btn-blue', 'btn-purple');
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
};

const changeClass = (e, r, a) => {
  e.classList.remove(r);
  e.classList.add(a);
};
```

```css
.btn-blue {
  background-color: #1d8dee;
}

.btn-blue:hover {
  background-color: #4fa7ee;
}

.btn-purple {
  background-color: #8064A2;
}

.btn-purple:hover {
  background-color: #7237e4;
}

.menus {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center; overflow: auto; white-space: nowrap;">
  <button class="btn btn-blue" id="btn1" onclick="toggle('menu1', 'btn1');">Button One</button> &nbsp;
  <button class="btn btn-purple" id="btn2" onclick="toggle('menu2', 'btn2');">Button Two</button>
</div>

<div id="menu1" class="menus" style="display: block;"><br>
  <p>Menu One</p>
</div>

<div id="menu2" class="menus"><br>
  <p>Menu Two</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you initialise your button CSS to the first colour you want, and include a `hidden` class, `classList` is more effective, and you don't have to set the `style` of the element anymore.
2. I've used [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) on the buttons and menus.

```js
// Cache the buttons and menu elements
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const menus = document.querySelectorAll('.menu');

// Attach listeners to the buttons
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleButton, false);
});

function handleButton(e) {
  
  // Grab the data attribute id from the button
  const button = e.target;
  const { id } = button.dataset;

  // Hide the menus
  menus.forEach(menu => {
    menu.classList.add('hidden');
  });

  // Target the menu with the corresponding button id
  const menu = document.querySelector(`.menu[data-id="${id}"]`);

  // Show the menu
  menu.classList.toggle('hidden');

  // Remove the btn-purple class from all the buttons
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.classList.remove('btn-purple');
  });

  // But add the class to the button that was clicked on
  button.classList.add('btn-purple');

};
```

```css
.btn { background-color: #1d8dee; }
.btn:hover { background-color: #4fa7ee; }
.btn-purple { background-color: #8064A2; }
.btn-purple:hover { background-color: #7237e4; }
.menu { text-align: center; }
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn" data-id="1">Button One</button>
  &nbsp;
  <button class="btn btn-purple" data-id="2">Button Two</button>
  &nbsp;
  <button class="btn btn-purple" data-id="3">Button Three</button>
</div>

<div data-id="1" class="menu"><br>
  <p>Menu One</p>
</div>

<div data-id="2" class="menu hidden"><br>
  <p>Menu Two</p>
</div>

<div data-id="3" class="menu hidden"><br>
  <p>Menu Three</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem here is that you always remove `btn-purple` and add `btn-blue`
while calling
`changeClass(button, 'btn-purple', 'btn-blue');`

You can acheive your result with https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp

Answer (score -1):

Is this the effect you were trying to achieve?

```js
window.toggle = (id, btn) => {
  const button = document.getElementById(btn);

  document.querySelectorAll('.menus').forEach(menu => {
    if (menu.style.display === 'block') {
      menu.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
  /*
    reverse the style/class for all buttons
  */
  document.querySelectorAll('button.btn').forEach(bttn=>{
    changeClass(bttn, 'btn-blue', 'btn-purple');
  })
  

  changeClass(button, 'btn-purple', 'btn-blue');
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
};

window.changeClass = (e, r, a) => {
  e.classList.remove(r);
  e.classList.add(a);
};
```

```css
.btn-blue {
  background-color: #1d8dee;
}

.btn-blue:hover {
  background-color: #4fa7ee;
}

.btn-purple {
  background-color: #8064A2;
}

.btn-purple:hover {
  background-color: #7237e4;
}

.menus {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  margin:1rem 0 0 0;
}

.btn{color:white;padding:1rem;margin:auto;}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center; overflow: auto; white-space: nowrap;">
  <button class="btn btn-blue" id="btn1" onclick="toggle('menu1', 'btn1');">Button One</button>
  <button class="btn btn-purple" id="btn2" onclick="toggle('menu2', 'btn2');">Button Two</button>
  <button class="btn btn-purple" id="btn3" onclick="toggle('menu3', 'btn3');">Button Three</button>
  <button class="btn btn-purple" id="btn4" onclick="toggle('menu4', 'btn4');">Button Four</button>
</div>

<div id="menu1" class="menus" style="display: block;">
  <p>Menu One</p>
</div>

<div id="menu2" class="menus">
  <p>Menu Two</p>
</div>

<div id="menu3" class="menus">
  <p>Menu Three</p>
</div>

<div id="menu4" class="menus">
  <p>Menu Four</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just like you are iterating over all the `.menus`, you can iterate over all the `.btn`s as well and compare them with the one that has just been clicked to figure out what classes to toggle.

There's usually no good reason to add methods into the `Window` scope, it can create conflicts and you may accidentally overwrite existing methods and introduce bugs.

[DOMTokenList.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/replace) can replace your `changeClass()` function, and the code to toggle `.menus` visibility can also be simplified to just a single line.

```js
let toggle = function (id, btn) {
  const button = document.getElementById(btn);

  document.querySelectorAll('.menus').forEach(menu => {
    menu.style.display = menu.id == id ? 'block' : 'none';
  });

  document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(btn => {
    if (btn == button)
      btn.classList.replace('btn-purple', 'btn-blue');
    else
      btn.classList.replace('btn-blue', 'btn-purple');
  });
};
```

```css
.btn-blue {
  background-color: #1d8dee;
}

.btn-blue:hover {
  background-color: #4fa7ee;
}

.btn-purple {
  background-color: #8064A2;
}

.btn-purple:hover {
  background-color: #7237e4;
}

.menus {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.btn {
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center; overflow: auto; white-space: nowrap;">
  <button class="btn btn-blue" id="btn1" onclick="toggle('menu1', 'btn1');">Button One</button> &nbsp;
  <button class="btn btn-purple" id="btn2" onclick="toggle('menu2', 'btn2');">Button Two</button>
</div>

<div id="menu1" class="menus" style="display: block;"><br>
  <p>Menu One</p>
</div>

<div id="menu2" class="menus"><br>
  <p>Menu Two</p>
</div>
```